# Is there a jmeter plugin to compare test duration against a predefined benchmark?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am a c# developer and my QA team implemented jmeter based test process, but I don't like their process. What I want is this:

Say I have 10 web api test cases and jmeter simulate 10 users.
When jmeter finishes each test, I want to compare the average duration against a predefined benhmark.

1. Test 1 is an easy one and I expect the average duration less than 1 second
2. Test 2 is a complicated one and I expect the average duration to be less than 5 second
3. Test x expect average duration to be less than N seconds
4. If any test's average duration is 10% higher than predefined number, the test result should be a fail.

My QA insists it can't be done in Jmeter, is it really the case? I am a c# developer and I can do above easily using nbomber with bit coding.

Answer (score 0):

1. 1-3 - [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)
2. 4 - [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) along with any Sampler somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group), there is [`TESTSTART.MS`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops) pre-defined variable which holds the time of test start. Getting current time, comparing it to the test start time and failing the request is not a big deal.

More information on the Assertions concept: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions)